# Issue with saturation after calculations in Java

Tags: java, math, overflow, calculator, polish

I'm creating a Reverse Polish Calculator and am having issues with saturation. I've implemented a stack, and have found the largest number I can get to without having the issue is 2147483647. So if I push this number to the stack, then add 1, the result I get is -214748364**8** (negative). What I need to do is instead of returning this negative number, return the original number 2147483647. Basically have this as a limit. The same applies to the negative side of things, where the limit is -2147483648. Let me know if I have missed any info or you need to see code.

Answer (score 0):

The largest `int` value is `2147483647` and the smallest is `-2147483648`. `int` values wrap around, so when you add `1` to `2147483647` you get `-2147483648` and when you subtract `1` from `-2147483648` you get `2147483647`.

If you don't want this behaviour you can do

```
int a = 2147483647;
a += 1.0;                   // a is still 2147483647
```

or

```
int a = 2147483647;
int b = (int) (a + 1.0);    // b is also 2147483647
```

These work because `a + 1.0` is calculated using `double` (no overflow) and the result is converted back to an `int` using the rule that numbers bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` just become `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get his solution to work? Using doubles I am returned with this 2.147483647E9. Any idea?

Comment: @GeorgeBurslem No, it won't work if you have any variables of type `double`. All the variables must have type `int`. If you want a solution using `int` you can do `int b = a == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? a : a + 1;` to add 1 and `int c = a == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? a : a - 1;` for subtracting 1.